# Cakephp 2.5 can not find an Oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, cakephp

I create a CakePhp model following the right CakePhp naming conventions and add into the `$sequence` property the name of the sequence as it was created on the Oracle database.

Inserting one record via sql plus was ok, but inserting data via Cakephp triggers the error:

```
[code] => 2289 
[message] => ORA-02289: the sequence does not exists 
[offset] => 7 [sqltext] => SELECT my_sql_table_seq.currval FROM dual
```

Even after cleaning up the tmp/cache content i see the same error as if cakephp try to guess the sequence name even having the sequence property named in the right way.

Is there a way to see why it happens ?

Comment: Probably the user your CakePhp is imperonate (using) has not the rights to see the sequence or you are missing a synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that you don't have a *sequence* called `my_sql_table_seq` in your oracle *schema*,
or perhaps you have this *sequence* in another *schema* and you're missing related *schema* name as `prefix` let's call `myschema` : `select myschema.my_sql_table_seq.currval from dual;`

( *provided your schema is granted for this sequence to execute* ) :

```
SQL> conn otherschema/password1
SQL> grant execute on my_sql_table_seq to myschema;
SQL> conn myschema/password2
SQL> select otherschema.my_sql_table_seq.currval from dual;
```

or just create a sequence :

```
SQL> conn myschema/password2
SQL> create sequence my_sql_table_seq increment by 1 minvalue 0;
SQL> select my_sql_table_seq.currval from dual;
```

Comment: if with sqlplus is working I don't think that create the sequence in another user (read schema) is a good idea...it is already in its schema...

Comment: @shadowsheep we don't know yet in its own schema. Perhaps created in any other schema but trying to call from  current schema. I'm mentioning about the possible cases.